# How to return a value from a function to another function with Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

This is my problem. I can not return the value of the `randomtext()` function to the main function.

I want the text to be selected to be copied and then pasted somewhere. Using a `Label` works, but when I use an `Entry` it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
def psw_generator():
    global gen
    genpassw = Tk()
    genpassw.title("password generator")

    entrypassw = Entry(parent, textvariable = gen, state = DISABLED)
    entrypassw.pack()


def randomtext():

    x = 0
    psw = ""
    lenght = 16
    full_char_table = "abcdef.."
    type = full_char_table

    gen = StringVar(value = psw)

    for x in range(int(lenght)):
        psw += type[int(random.randrange(len(type)))]
        x += 1

    return gen
```

Comment: Tkinter apps are "user-event driven" which mean that everything has to happen while the `mainloop()` is running. For what you're doing that means you will need to make `randomtext()`get called by one of its interface widgets like a `Button` or `Entry` and specifying something like `command=randomtext` when its created. The are called "event-handlers" and "callback" functions. Any decent `tkinter` tutorial will have examples showing the detail of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in this code so I had solved them and your finished code is here:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

global gen
genpassw = Tk()
gen = StringVar()
genpassw.title("password generator")

entrypassw = Entry(genpassw, textvariable = gen, state = DISABLED)
entrypassw.pack()
def randomtext():
    global gen
    x = 0
    psw = ""
    length = 16
    full_char_table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"


    for x in range(int(length)):
        psw += full_char_table[random.randint(0,len(full_char_table)-1)]

    gen.set(psw)

randomtext()
genpassw.mainloop()
```

So have a look at your problems

```
entrypassw = Entry(parent, textvariable = gen, state = DISABLED)
```

What is 'parent' in the entry widget you need to use genpassw because that is your parent widget.

```
type = full_char_table
```

You had used 'type' as a variable, 'type' is builtin function of python so you cannot use it.

```
x += 1
```

No need to use increment in for loop>>  x += 1

```
entrypassw = Entry(parent, textvariable = gen, state = DISABLED)
entrypassw.pack()

return gen
```

You are returning gen.Before you described them as text variable for widget, and now you are returning it. It is deprecated.

You must use mainloop to make your GUI run.

```
genpassw.mainloop()
```